# How to create database tables in sqlite c# using a text file?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, oop

I would like to create tables of sqlite database in c#. However, I would like to use a text file to store model names that will be created in the system. How do I establish that using c#?

I have successfully read the file content. However, stuck in creating tables using the strings.

```
Customer
CustomerAgent
CustomerAddress
```

Example of a class:

```
Table["Customer"]
public class Customer
{
    [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey, Unique] public int UniqueId { get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I try to read class names from text file:

```
try
{
    string filePath = "models.txt";

    string[] modelNames = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    foreach (string modelName in modelNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Creating table for model: {modelName}");
        // Here I have to create table in database normally I do like this: SqliteConnection.CreateTable<ClassName>();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do. Can you give an example flow? What's in the text file, how should your program process it, and what would the result look like in the database schema?

Comment: a text-file of model-names is not particularly useful - what about columns, indexes, constraints, etc etc? Why not use a `.sql` file that contains actual `CREATE TABLE ...` statements instead?

Comment: Text file has all the class names that should be created as tables in sqlite database. Program should process it using sqlite-net-sqlcipher's SQLiteConnection.CreateTable function.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with specific examples. Describing your code is not as good as _showing_ your code. See [ask].

Comment: @Dai columns, indexes and other related information is contained in class.

Comment: Show an example of the content of the text file, the code you have made to read it and an example of such a class. Is it a class in you current project?

Comment: Just curious: why the text file? If you can put the classnames in a text file, you can put them in code, right?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have added code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/).

```
foreach (string modelName in modelNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Creating table for model: {modelName}");
    // You may add necessary controls etc.
    SqliteConnection.CreateTable<Type.GetType(modelName)>();
}
```